# silverlight combobox invokecommandaction on selectionchanged event cannot pass parameter

Tags: silverlight, command

I have a combobox, using databinding and MVVM pattern. Everytime the user changes the selection, I added an event trigger, and a command is executed. the code is the following:

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="myComboBox" Width="150" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
                                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=myComboBox}" />
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </ComboBox>
```

the problem is that the parameter it passes is always null.

Comment: Can you post the code of your ViewModel? Also where do you set the DataContext for your view? Because from the XAML/Binding point of view your code looks OK.

Comment: @nemesv I have an IEnumerable<Item> Items property in my ViewModel, which is properly initialized, data is loaded, and the combobox items are loaded correctly on UI. Everything else is working great, only the parameter is always null.

Comment: In this case how does your LoadCommand looks like? Which ICommand implementation do you use?

Comment: @nemesv I have a class DelegateCommand, implementing ICommand. In my ViewModel there is a property public DelegateCommand LoadCommand { get; set; }, initialized and then the code to execute it private void ExecuteLoad(object parameter)
        {
            var selected = (Item)parameter;

Comment: the problem is not the cast to Item, the parameter is null

Comment: Can you show the implementation of the DelegateCommand? Or is it comming from a MVVM library? Because I've created a simple repro and for me your XAML is working...

Comment: public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
    {
        public DelegateCommand(Action<object> executeMethod);
        public DelegateCommand(Action<object> executeMethod, Func<object, bool> canExecuteMethod);
        public DelegateCommand(Action<object> executeMethod, Func<object, bool> canExecuteMethod, bool isAutomaticRequeryDisabled);

Comment: public bool IsAutomaticRequeryDisabled { get; set; }
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;        
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter);      
        public void Execute(object parameter);        
        protected virtual void OnCanExecuteChanged();      
        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }

Answer (score 0):

I changed the parameter from SelectedItem to SelectedIndex, this way I get the parameter and it is not null. Then i get my object using the index.